# Camellia Sbox - Linear Approximation Probability

Tags: aes, s-boxes, camellia

One Page 7, of Document [Camellia Design and Analysis](https://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/eng/camellia/dl/reference/sac_camellia.pdf)

The author says,

> In the case of Camellia, the maximum diferential/linear probabilities of s-boxes are $2^{-6}$.

Since Camellia S-boxes are made up from Affine-Inverse-Affine Transformation in $GF(2^8)$ which has Linear Approximation Probability of $2^{-4}$, then why authors wrote it $2^{-6}$.

Does Camellia S-boxes have Linear Approximation probability of $2^{-6}$ or $2^{-4}$?

any body calculated it?

Comment: it has been answered at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41702/linear-approximation-and-linear-probability-of-camellia-sbox

Comment: The same question is asked elsewhere , you can find the answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41702/linear-approximation-and-linear-probability-of-camellia-sbox/41725#41725)

Comment: @hardyrama your referred link is already mentioned in the above comment.