# Linear Approximation and Linear Probability of Camellia Sbox

Tags: s-boxes, camellia

In this article,[Analysis of Camellia](https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/enc/CRYPTREC/fy15/doc/1082_camellia.pdf) (para **2. Differential and linear cryptanalysis**, page 3), it says

> The **maximum bias of a linear approximation** through one S-box is $2^{-4}$
>   , which gives a **linear probability** of $2^{-6}$

what does this mean? isn't the linear approximation probability $2^{-4}$?

[See This Question Too](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41481/camellia-sbox-linear-approximation-probability)

Comment: Can you specify the exact location of your quote?

Comment: check the referenced paper

Answer (score 6):

Let $LP$ be the linear probability (also called "correlation potential"), $Cor$ be the correlation coefficient and $\epsilon$ be the bias of a linear approximation. Then

$LP = Cor^2 = (2\times \epsilon)^2$.

So, if $\epsilon=2^{-4}$, then $LP = ({2\times 2^{-4}})^2=2^{-6}$.

[1] Daemen, J., Rijmen, V.: Probability distributions of correlation and differentials in block ciphers. J. Mathematical Cryptology 1(3), 221–242 (2007). DOI 10.1515/JMC.2007.011. URL http://jda.noekeon.org/JDA_VRI_Stat_2007.pdf